# Pause the game (ActionScript 3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have written the game. It starts at once, when running the program. EVERYTHING works in one Document Class. Now, I want to do some basic intro, for example, animated countdown before the game starts. How can I kinda pause the game? there is only one frame on the main timeline which contains the background.

Comment: Put in a timer before the game code starts.  You'll need to ask a much more details question with code examples before you can get a specific answer

Comment: how can i make document class to start on the second or some other frame?

Comment: You don't. Rather than having your code start the game, you make the code start your timer animation and only start the game when it is completed. Maybe you would get a clearer answer if you posted your code.

Comment: @ Nika Gamkrelidze : Study the basics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your animation based  on the timer.

When start the timer:

```
timer.start();
last_time = getTimer();
```

when pause the timer:

```
timer.stop();
pause_timer = getTimer() - last_time;
```

when resume the timer:

```
last_time = getTimer();
timer.start();
```

Hope, it will helps you.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Antony's answer above, if you are using event listeners to handle the game loop actions, you can simply remove them to pause the game and then add them again to re-start it.  For example:

```
package com.mygame.logic{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Bitmap; 
import fl.controls.Button; //to get this code to work you have to drag a UI component to your 
//movie's library or Flash won't recognize it.
public class mygame extends MovieClip{   //this is to be the main document class for the .fla
private var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(...); //fill in constructor with relevant data
private var myButton:Button = new Button();
private var paused:Boolean = false;
public mygame(){
  bmp.x = 100;
  bmp.y = 100;
  myButton.x = 200;
  myButton.y = 200;
  this.addChild(bmp);
  this.addChild(myButton);
  this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, main);
  myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ON_CLICK, pause);
}
public function main(e:Event):void{
  bmp.x += 1.0;
}
public function pause(e:MouseEvent):void{
  if (!paused){
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, main);
    this.paused = true;
  }
  else{
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, main);
    this.paused = false;
  }
}
```

and that should do it for a basic pause function.  You can expand upon the above to make a nice HUD for the player with nicely named and colored buttons etc. for pausing/restarting the game, use tweens to make the HUD transition onto the screen nicely...

hope it helps,
CCJ